# jQuery: How to call a function before unload window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to call a function before closing a window.

For example I want to call ajax before closing page. I am using following code but its not working.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
        $.ajax({
        url:'logout.php',
        type:'POST'
          });
});
```

What is the best way to call function before closing the window?

Answer (score 0):

You code is most likely being run, but as it starts a *asynchronous* ajax request and the browser tears down the page immediately after triggering `onbeforeunload`, the request probably never gets sent (or if it gets sent, probably gets aborted).

The event handler for `onbeforeunload` is only allowed to do a **very** limited set of things (and the list varies from browser to browser, and the list frequently changes as browsers update things). For that reason, using `onbeforeunload` for anything other than the **one purpose** for which it was intended, giving you a last ditch chance to warn the user of losing information by leaving the page, is not a good idea.

Comment: So what do you think? what is the best solution for this kind of requirement?

Comment: @user3043360: Some browsers may allow a *synchronous* ajax request (others won't). But I would just go another way entirely, don't expect to be able to do anything when the user closes the window. Instead, come at the requirement another way. For instance: If the purpose of the ajax request is to say "the user has closed the window," how about inverting that and saying you'll do an ajax request every once in a while (stopping if the user is inactive for more than a few minutes) to tell the server "the user is still on the page"? Or better yet, just time out inactive sessions on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written just makes an ajax call, but even before the call can be made, your window will be exit. And even if the request is sent, it may be aborted in between.

Comment: I must have to run logout.php upon closing page. So I want some solution that can resolve this. Do you think it is possible?

Comment: @user3043360: It's an anti-pattern and it **will** break. Instead, just time out inactive sessions.

Comment: @user3043360, You cannot just rely on that event. This is because, The end user may end the browser process from task manager itself. Hence you instead should go for session timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
   function WinClose() {
             $.ajax({
               url:'logout.php',
               type:'POST'
             });
             return false;
    }
    window.onbeforeunload = WinClose;
```

Write this code in `<head>`